# Why MySQL is still "using temporary" when update by primary key?

Tags: mysql, update, mysql-5.6

I have a partitioned mysql table, table size is about 100M rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `nearby` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`nearby_1` varchar(750) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`nearby_2` varchar(750) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`nearby_3` varchar(750) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`nearby_4` varchar(750) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`nearby_5` varchar(750) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (id)
PARTITIONS 30 */;
```

And I'm using following query to update this table (in multiprocess):

```
update nearby set nearby_5 =
"532487838^620340056^569758570^598224990^490445906^485712257^560741695^584147604^504840723^574686588^499373888^514048867^574839522^555681829^528849288^482987618^621473564^527953408^509892347^575024990^533233841^528365873^661634374^508770161^499694389^514308586^"
where id = 150986046
```

From what I understand this query should be fast because it's updating by primary key. But the explain in mysql tells me it's "using temporary":

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |  ref  | rows |            Extra             |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | nearby | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | const |    1 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: I couldn't see nearby_forsale column in the table definition!! (I'll assume you meant nearby_5)
Are you using 5.7 to run explain against UPDATE? The explain plan you shared says the "range" while, I guess I'd expect "const" instead!! Can you share what explain query you ran?

Comment: Sorry about the column name. I changed the name in the schema. But I didn't touch the explain query. Here's a screenshot of the explain http://grab.by/MbUe

Comment: This is MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Also the explain query I ran is just "explain" + the query I posted above.

Comment: Question: why are you partitioning the PK by hash?

Comment: using temporary, not always mean using temporary :-) it as well mean using buffer. in this case may be because long column with compressed format and it use buffer for update single row. but still it not exactly mean create temporary table.

Comment: @greenlitmysql Is it not a good idea to partition PK by hash? basically my idea was to not let the table grow too big, so I divide it into small partitions. Could you elaborate on why it's not good? I didn't know that's bad..

Comment: @a_vlad I see. Thank you for the explanation. That makes sense. Do you have any doc or article that I can refer to? thank you!

Comment: check there -  http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=593009

Comment: Interesting.. And good to know!

Comment: @Suanmeiguo: I would not partition by hash on a PK, especially for innodb tables which uses clustered index. It also depends how many rows you have in your table. Clustered index are very fast when accessed by key whether you select, update or delete. The goal of partitioning is to group same data together whether it's by month or days, or by zip codes ; where partition by list would probably be appropriate.

Comment: I think this is another example of why `PARTITION BY HASH` is worse than useless.

Comment: @Suanmeiguo - "not let the table grow too big".  No.  Too big (in InnoDB) is when a table hits 32 terabytes.